# Changes have no impact on loaded script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

After I have changed a JavaScript file I don't get the changes in `*.js` dynamic.
When I debug I see that no changes had any impact on the `*.js` dynamic.

What should I do to get the changes to make any impact?

**Background**

I have changed the page with a component that to be dydnamisk between two different components that are placed in a placeholder. To access the control I change the JavaScript with `placeholder.contControls[0]` to get a property in the control to be write to.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a caching issue. Add a query parameter to the file URL, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js?v=2"></script>
```

Comment: or you can use Paul Irish's trick using foo.001.js (and incrementing the 001 every time you push to production)